# What data does Firefox use to display virus warnings?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, virus

I tried to download a zip file from a legit-looking site using Firefox, when I was shown a warning message "This file contains a virus or malware":
[image]

Where does this information come from? Is there a way to show any details, like what virus specifically is detected, so that I can make an informed decision about how to proceed?

I didn't install any antivirus software, but perhaps Windows 10 has something built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla wrote a blog article about this, which can be found here https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/08/01/enhancing-download-protection-in-firefox/

Short answer - it's driven by Google's "Safe Browsing Service"

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I uploaded the file to an online virus scanner which found nothing, so the message I got is almost certainly a false positive from Safe Browsing.